# How many levels does Firebase ChildEventListener listen to

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My current Android application uses [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/) to store user data.

My data has the following "*structure*" (*and/or levels*)

```
my-android-app.firebaseio.com/level0/level1/UUID1/UUID2
```

data objects are stored at UUID2 that resemble this

```
{
   "Students":[
      {
         "Name":"Amit Goenka",
         "Major":"Physics"
      },
      {
         "Name":"Smita Pallod",
         "Major":"Chemistry"
      },
      {
         "Name":"Rajeev Sen",
         "Major":"Mathematics"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to be able to detect when child data is added, removed or changed etc
below (at) UUID2, however I only want to set up my ChildEventListener using this path

```
android-app.firebaseio.com/level0/level1
```

is this possible?

During my test so far I have had to specify the full path of:-

```
my-android-app.firebaseio.com/level0/level1/UUID1/UUID2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase will fire a `child_*` event for any change under the level where you register the correct listener. But it will only fire `child_added`/`child_removed` for nodes added/removed *directly* under the level where you registered. For other changes, it will fire `child_changed` and possibly `child_moved`.

Your options:

- [flatten the tree](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html)
- listen to `value` events
- listen to all `child_` events and figure out the changes

Comment: flattening my tree is not an option. The two lower levels UUID1 and UUID2, are randomly generated level names and must exist. Are you saying that ValueEventListener can be set at this level my-android-app.firebaseio.com/level0/level1/ and they can detect data changes at my-android-app.firebaseio.com/level0/level1/UUID1/UUID2 level?

Comment: The `value` event will fire whenever anything under the location you attached it to changes. But you'll have to re-calculate the UI updates, which may be expensive. Flattening the tree is usually the best option. Can you elaborate why that isn't an option?

Comment: My Android application doesn't have ui directly linked to this data, so recalculating the ui isn't an issue. I cannot flatten as the randomly generated UUID levels segregate users data and enforce anonymity. So if I understand you corectly I can set a value event at ....level0/level1 and this will fire when children are added below /UUID1/UUID2?

Comment: Yes. The `value` event will fire whenever anything under the location you attached it to changes.